# Why isn't Microsoft.Powershell.Core listed when I in the results of Get-Module?

Tags: powershell

Why isn't the core Powershell module **Microsoft.Powershell.Core** listed in the results of the `Get-Module` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-module?view=powershell-5.1#notes) for `Get-Module` specify:

> Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, the core commands that are included in Windows PowerShell are packaged in modules. **The exception is Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, which is a snap-in (PSSnapin)**. By default, only the Microsoft.PowerShell.Core snap-in is added to the session. Modules are imported automatically on first use and you can use the Import-Module cmdlet to import them.

(emphasis mine)

If you run [`Get-PSSnapin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-pssnapin?view=powershell-5.1) instead, you do indeed see it:

```
PS C:\Users\JamesThorpe> get-pssnapin

Name        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core
PSVersion   : 5.1.15063.502
Description : This Windows PowerShell snap-in contains cmdlets used to manage components of Windows PowerShell.
```